# When or in what case should I use Optional to check null?

Tags: java, java-8

Should I always use the Optional to check null in Java 8?

And is it a good practice that I use it in my DAO layer? Here's a snippet code of my DAO layer:

```
public Optional<Tag> retrieveTagByValue(String tagValue) {
    Tag tag = null;
    try {
        tag = em.createNamedQuery("Tag.findByValue", Tag.class)
                .setParameter("tagValue", tagValue)
                .getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(tag);
}
```

Because in my Service layer, I want to know whether the tag is null or not, if it is null then I create a new tag. So I am wondering should I use Optional in this case, is there any better ways to improve this method? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Approach this from a client perspective. Is life easier when you call the method and get a Optional? Ways to improve the method: Don't write the exception to System.out

Comment: @wero In my Service layer, I want to know if the tag is null, if so then create a new tag, so I want the NoResultException be caught and then print something. What should I do if "Don't write the exception to System.out"?Thank you~~

Comment: you decided to convert the ill designed `NoResultException` into a null result (or an Optional with a null value). Therefore the catch block should be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’d call your example an anti-pattern unnecessarily introducing `null`, regardless of how your perform the subsequent `null`-check.

Consider:

```
public Optional<Tag> retrieveTagByValue(String tagValue) {
    try {
        Tag tag = em.createNamedQuery("Tag.findByValue", Tag.class)
                .setParameter("tagValue", tagValue)
                .getSingleResult();
        return Optional.of(tag);
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

This way, we’re not using `Optional` to perform a `null` check, we’re using it to not introduce a `null` in the first place.

It’s still debatable whether it is an improvement for the caller, to get an empty `Optional` in the erroneous case and having to loop-back and parse the standard output to find out the actual reason, compared to catching a meaningful exception.

But if not having a result is considered to be within the normal operation of this method (compare with `Stream.findAny()`), returning an empty `Optional` is fine, but then, it shouldn’t be necessary to print a message to `System.out`.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I always use the Optional to check null in Java 8?

If a method would return `null` in Java 7 and lower then you should use `Optional.empty()` in Java 8. Using `Optional` helps you to get rid of `null` checks and makes code easier to read. `Optional` is although used in streams.

I would rewrite the code in the following manner:

```
public Optional<Tag> retrieveTagByValue(String tagValue) {
    try {
        Tag tag = em.createNamedQuery("Tag.findByValue", Tag.class)
            .setParameter("tagValue", tagValue)
            .getSingleResult();       
        return Optional.of(tag);
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

It's not considered to be a good practice to use `System.out...` for logging, you should use some logging library instead.

> And is it a good practice that I use it in my DAO layer?

Personally, I would replace DAO with repository (check out Spring Data) and I would use `Optional` in Service layer instead.

Comment: and maybe I should use java.util.logging.Logger ?

Comment: @MarcuX I would go with SLF4J which is a facade for common logging frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know whether the tag is null or not

than this is the *perfect case* to use Optional. And you got your explanations about how to refactor your code, but think about the *caller* of this method.

You are being very explicit that this method might return a result that is not present - expressed via `Optional.empty` or a result that might be present, expressed via `Optional.get/isPresent` etc. This way you *force* the caller to make some decisions based on whether the results in present or not. That is simply not the case when returning a reference.